# Why cannot the project location be at the filesystem root?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to put my project in a flash drive `D:/`  but the Android Studio complains  as follows.

[image]

I am interested to know the reason why the project location cannot be at the filesystem root.

Comment: The project location path has to include the folder for the project. If it's just `D:/` then the `app`, `.idea`, and other folders will be added directly to `D:/`. It's probably just an organizational limitation, but it wouldn't make sense for your whole D drive to be just for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive Root Can't be Project Location. Each Project needs a root folder. This folder is the holder of this project. And when you browse all the project from Open Project in Android studio You will see that your project folder icon is different than other normal folder and it marks that it's a android studio project. See the shots bellow..

[image]

[image]

Here I have Created Test Project for in F Drive inside the Hello folder.
Then when I go through the Open existing project the Hello folder shows its a project. The folder turns into a project file itself, more accurately it's the project holder.

Every project need this project holder. A drive/partition root can't be a project holder . It's by default system rules.